# C++ DLL compiles with different dependencies on TFS build machine

Tags: c++, dll

Our desktop application contains several C++ DLL's in a dependency relationship.  DLL "A" is referenced by DLL "B" which is referenced by DLL "C".  These are all DLL's written by us.

When we compile on a developer workstation, the resulting DLL "C" works correctly at runtime.  If we examine it using Dependency Walker, we can see that it depends upon DLL "B".  However, if we let TFS build the solution using the same configuration (as far as we can tell) the resulting "C" causes a runtime error.

When we examine the TFS output of "C" with Dependency Walker, there is no reference to "B".

What is likely to cause this type of behavior?  I suppose that I'm not clear on how the dependency information is being added to the DLL, since there are no dependencies called out in VS2008 project properties.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: On developer workstation you build Debug or Release version? Are you building it in one solution?

Comment: Release version in both cases.  If I do a debug build on the TFS server it does include the right dependencies.  It's a solution build.

Comment: So check your release configuration. You can try use visual studio on your build machine and check if solution is building manually there.

Comment: Using VS manually on the TFS build machine works, but it generates a DLL with the same issue we see from automated builds.  "C" doesn't reference "B".

Comment: Still searching for this answer.  Anyone have a clue?